# Caption Style Changes

Tags: css

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

Novice HTML user: I am currently using the Baguette gallery (v1.8.1) code for my gallery site. 
Tutorial: http://yifangdi.blogspot.com/2017/05/baguetteboxjs-simple-and-easy-to-use.html

I want to change the font style of the "data-caption" 
example code:
or implement a hover-over caption .css style rule.

**CSS for gallery grid:**

```js
body {
  background - image: linear - gradient(to top, #d3c081 % , #d3c081 75 % , #d3c081 100 % );
  min - height: 100 vh;
  font: normal 16 px sans - serif;
  padding: 100 px 0;
}

.container.gallery - container {
    background - color: #163049;
      color: # 163049;
    min - height: 100 vh;
    border - radius: 20 px;
    box - shadow: 0 8 px 15 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  }

  .gallery - container h1 {
    text - align: center;
    margin - top: 70 px;
    font - family: 'Droid Sans', sans - serif;
    font - weight: bold;
  }

  .gallery - container p.page - description {
    text - align: center;
    max - width: 800 px;
    margin: 25 px auto;
    color: #888;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .tz-gallery {
      padding: 40px;
    }
    
    .tz-gallery .lightbox img {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .tz-gallery .lightbox img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.05);
      box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
    .tz-gallery img {
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .baguetteBox-button {
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 768px) {
      body {
        padding: 100px 0;
      }
      .container.gallery-container {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container gallery-container">
  <div class="tz-gallery">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a class="lightbox" href="images/park.jpg" data-caption="The Park">
          <img src="images/park.jpg" alt="Park">
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d3c081%, #d3c081 75%, #d3c081 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font: normal 16px sans-serif;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.container.gallery-container {
  background-color: #163049;
  color: #163049;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.gallery-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gallery-container p.page-description {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tz-gallery {
  padding: 40px;
}

.tz-gallery .lightbox img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.tz-gallery .lightbox img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.tz-gallery img {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.baguetteBox-button {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    padding: 100px 0;
  }
  .container.gallery-container {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

[data-caption="The Park"] { 
  font: italic 16px sans-serif; 
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container gallery-container">
  <div class="tz-gallery">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a class="lightbox" href="images/park.jpg" data-caption="The Park">
          <img src="images/park.jpg" alt="Park">
        </a>
    </div>

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

use `[data-caption]` like below

```
[data-caption="The Park"] { 
  font: italic 16px sans-serif; 
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: I added this to my .css page and nothing changed. [data-caption="The Park"] {
font-style: italic;font: normal 16px sans-serif; font-size: 2em; }

Comment: use `font: italic 16px sans-serif;`  instead `font-style: italic;` i updated my code with code snippet. pls check.

Comment: What you are telling is probably correct. I inspected the code of my page. Its calling for a <figcaption id=" baguette box...."></figcaption>. Problem is that I cant modify the .css for the baguette box.